Common mode choke placement in DC input circuit
I have a PCB that is currently not passing EMC tests. The most problematic issue is common mode noise on the power line, thus a common mode choke was proposed. My circuit already includes over-voltage protection, reverse voltage protection and a T-filter before the 24V line is connected to a SMPS. The PCB is powered from a 230V --> 24V SMPS with no connection to PE.
I have found the SRF3225TP-501Y common mode choke which from what I can read should have a high attenuation in the problematic frequency area (68-80MHz). My question is how to connect the choke properly to my circuit, and also where it should be placed.
I have read this post which eliminates my first thought (upper drawing), which makes a lot of sense.
The middle drawing seems more correct, but I am not sure if the choke can be damaged by being placed before the diode.
The bottom drawing seems most logical to me. It separates GND1 which is the PSU ground and GND which is the PCB ground planes. I think this design is better because the diode comes first, then reverse voltage protection, and then the choke and T filter.
Any thoughts on what is best practice here? I have never used a common mode choke before, so I am fumbling in the dark... Would also appreciate tips on application notes or books that describes this topic in further detail.


The most problematic issue is common mode noise on the power line The common mode noise appears on both + and – lines relative to another point which has a different electrical potential. To be more clear, there must be a separate point to which the power inputs can be referenced. What is this point in your system/design? I can't see anything other than 24V + and – connections. For example, in a mains system, there are L (live), N (neutral) and PE (earth). The CM noise appears on L and N relative to PE which is at a different potential than both L and N. Is there such a point in your system?

To add to Rohat's comment -- EMC is a complex, interconnected topic, and EMC problems are holistic in nature.  There is generally very little that can be said about a problem without also completely describing the setup and environment: schematics, PCB layout, and photos, are most likely required for a reasonably complete and confident answer.

Understand that -- at least as currently written -- we have to assume you have independently verified that a CMC in this location will solve your problem. Otherwise, we cannot offer insight as to whether it will help or not.

So the 24V input is fed from a 230V --> 24V switch mode power supply. It is only connected to the system via + and - going out of the SMPS, thus no PE point available in my system. Can the CMC work in any of the setups shown above, or is it useless without any reference to PE or similar?

@eidetech So the 24V input is fed from a 230V --> 24V switch mode power supply.  that's an important detail, put it into your question by editing it. Does your off-mains SMPS have a PE connection to the mains? If it does then you may have a common mode noise on both + and - rails if and only if your PCB has a connection to the PE. Otherwise the CMC, well, wouldn't be totally useless: It won't work as a CM filter, but its leakages along with the capacitors across the supply rails will work as a differential mode filter.

Edited the question now, thanks. There is no PE connection, so I guess what you are describing lastly here is applying. I will give it a go and see what results we get.

As long as the layout area of the pre-CMC section, in the bottom version, is kept small, it's more or less equivalent to the middle case.
The top case is out, as you note.  With one winding shorted, magnetizing (CM) inductance is nil, and the choke reduces to just stray/leakage inductance as DM filtering.  The tee filters will do more (but see below).
Regarding ratings: it's a dumb ball of wire and ceramic.  It will eventually arc over, but it would take quite a strong surge to exceed breakdown voltage (typically 100s V for the enameled wire used), in either position with respec to the TVS.  Current rating is on a continuous basis only, and much higher can be handled in surge.  SMAJ is not a big TVS, and will itself blow up before the CMC starts to melt -- in a load dump scenario, let's say.  It might be a concern in reverse conduction (but more on that below).
That said, there are instances of strong (particularly, fast) surges.  A direct ESD hit to one or the other input terminal, might well cause insulation breakdown.  But notice that, even in this extreme, more voltage drops along the device (common mode) than between wires (differential), and we should assume any breakdown of the enamel insulation compromises it (i.e., the spark might jump from turn to turn of the same wire, or between both wires).  This is true regardless of CMC vs. TVS position -- even with bypass or TVS between +/- on both ends of the CMC, we expect such transient CM voltage regardless.  The ESD solution (to avoid CMC breakdown) thus must be different.
ESD, needs to be sunk to a common ground reference plane or shield, so that current isn't flowing into the circuit and causing possible problems such as above.  A spark gap, MOV, TVS, bypass capacitors, or direct connection to chassis or enclosure ground, might be employed to achieve this.
Whether any of these (or the below) concerns are applicable to your system, we cannot know [as written]; I have to assume you know your system well enough to know whether they are relevant, and how and when to apply them.
Things You Didn't Ask But Are Worth Noting

Beware that those tee filters are just as generic as you assume: regular ferrite beads and chip caps stuck together.  The caps may be C0G (excellent), or X7R or the like (middling, but acceptable at the small value shown here), but the ferrite beads will saturate at modest currents.  They're almost never rated for impedance under DC bias, so you don't really know how much the filtering will decrease under load.  For reference, a typical 120Ω 1206 chip bead saturates significantly (impedance -30%) in the 100-300mA range, and literal beads (beads on leads, wound broadband, etc.) a few amperes give or take.  Parts are available with higher saturation current (have seen some WE parts doing a few amperes, at modest (10s Ω) impedance, in normal package sizes), or you can choose an inductor per se (rated for Isat, Idc and L -- usually without the R characteristic of FBs though, which will need to be substituted with R+Cs around them instead of hard Cs).

Saturation applies to the CMC as well.  Ensure either the 24V supply, or other connections to the circuit, are isolated so that there are no DC "sneak" paths around the circuit that can put unbalanced bias current through the CMC.  (Another common name for these is "current compensating choke", as the currents should be equal and opposite: this is how they achieve large inductances in small packages.)  A typical CMC of this size and construction will saturate at about 50mA, so it doesn't take much.

The TVS is unidirectional, and ahead of the polarity protection circuit, which seems unintended, an oversight.  Just use a bidirectional (suffix -CA) type, and ensure the transistor has adequate rating for the application.

Fusing isn't shown.  Be sure it is adequate for the nominal load, and the fusing (I2t) rating of all relevant components.  (Not that most things are rated as such, unfortunately..)



Thank you for the comprehensive answer. The common mode choke has been suggested by the EMC expert doing the tests for me. So I do not know for sure that it will solve anything, but for the next revision of the PCB I wanted to try it out.
I noticed you commented on the TVS being unidirectional, why would you want to change it to a bidirectional one? Also why should it not be ahead of the reverse voltage protection?

It's a diode in the forward direction (reverse voltage), shorting the input rather than letting the reverse protection circuit do its job.

Thanks @Tim Williams
